# Cannot Found CordovaActivity and classes in Cordova Project

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova project cannot found its activity and JAVA classes. I have already set SDK path, but i don't know why i cannot find its class. I get like below image :

[image]

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve here? The idea behind Cordova apps is that you never have to touch the java files. Have you tried with Visual Studio? It can manage Cordova apps much easier than NetBeans or any other IDE for the matter.

Comment: i will use visual studio@andreszs